# How do I change the state of a switch in Android studio via a button?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an app using Android Studio where if a person presses a button, the state of a switch in the app changes from on to off and vice versa. (the app would allow someone to turn all in app switches on by pressing a button and all in app switches off by pressing another one).

I don't know how to link the two together, so any help would be appreciated. I don't have any code to show for it, as I don't know from where I can start.

Here are two pictures in case it helps, please don't laugh, it is my first android app :)
[image]

Comment: Hello, do you mean physical lamp switch?

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I'll edit the question in a second. It's my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: welcome here .. You may have a look at [`ToogleButtons`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton)

Comment: That actually would help a lot. Changing the two buttons I have into a toggle button. The problem I am now facing is what code is necessary to actually turn the switches off or on in the IF statement of the togglebutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `ToggleButton` to your layout, there're more than one type in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton)

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Unselected"
    android:textOn="Selected" />
```

And listen to its check state by adding `OnCheckedChangeListener`, and change the state accordingly:

```
ToggleButton button = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
            // State is On
            // Run your code you want whenever the sate is ON

        } else {
            // State is OFF
            // Run your code you want whenever the sate is OFF
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
Any time the view of your app changes it's state (button pressed) you can listen to that event attaching and Obsever to a MutableLiveData, allowing to react to changes (and changing the switch position)

On a high level view, the code would look like this:

```
onCreate {
  MutableLiveData buttonPressed = false;
}

onCreateView {
  Switch switch = getSwitch();

  Button button = getButton();
  button.onClick {
    buttonPressed.value = true;
  }

  buttonPressed.observe {
   switch.toggle(); 
  }
}
```